# Google Maps API error, how to change organization?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

We have recently changed URL to our company's website. From tcodevelopment.com to tcocertified.com.

I can't get the Google Map API to work. It used to work. I guess the problem is that the organization is set to tcodevelopment.com in console.developers.google.com.

The JavaScript console returns this error message:
"Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError"

When trying to create a new project in Google APIs, the organization is set to tcodevelopment.com, and I can't figure out how to change this.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAKdD.png)

Help would be very much appreciated!

Kind regards,
Pete

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Answer (score 1):

You now need a key.  Your old domain was probably "grandfathered" for keyless access (assuming you aren't using a key, which is what that error indicates)